# How can i make my placeholder multiline if the Pacholder text is too long

Tags: html, css, angular

Below code is my html code. I want to make the placeholder multiline.How can i achieve it. I have few other option but still unable to solve it.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 require">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-select autofocus placeholder="Are you of Aboriginal and/or Torres Strait Islander origin?" formControlName="islandOriginID"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formControls.islandOriginID.errors }" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let island of islandOrigin" [value]="island.id">
              {{island.globalCodeValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="formControls.islandOriginID.errors">
            Please select island origin
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

Below image is how it shows currently. Placeholder cuts in half
[image]

I want to make it something like this instead of

`Are you of Aboriginal and/or Torres Strait Islander origin?`  --->This cuts in half.

I want to make it multiline like this

```
Are you of Aboriginal and/or Torres Strait
 Islander origin?
```

Comment: The `.mdc-floating-label` class applies `white-space: no-wrap`, so that is the first thing you would need to overwrite. Whether the rest of it will already grow in height automatically, or needs further modifications, you'd have to check.

Comment: (And of course this is once a again a perfect example of why "floating labels" are rather problematic to begin with. If a text this long is needed to understand the _meaning_ of the field, then it should much rather be a _proper_ label above the field, than get stuffed into the placeholder. Accessibility & usability should come _before_ "designer's vanity.")

Comment: A placeholder is supposed to be, well, a placeholder - an indication of the type of answer required. It is not the right thing to use to explain to the user what the question is - that is the function of a label element as pointed out by @CBroe.  Also, in the specific case given this is a yes/no answer and a correctly labelled checkbox might be more suitable for the user.

Comment: @AHaworth _"given this is a yes/no answer"_ - not sure it actually is, it looks like they are looping over a list of given islands there to create options? "None" appears to be one of the choices according to the screenshot, but I am guessing the other options would be actual islands here then - which would mean even the _phrasing_ of the question is rather off to begin with :-)

Comment: @cbroe I see your point.